# Creating Table with Parent Related Lists on Child record email template

Tags: visualforce, email

I have built a visual force email template and I need to add a table.

The table should hold the related list of the parent record.

For example, I have a customer who has multiple invoices - I email out the invoice but want to show all other invoices attached to the customer in a table.

The invoice is the child object

Can someone please help

Comment: It would help if you showed what you have written so far and pointed out where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Hi Martin, the email template works fine as above I need to add a table from the parent related lists. I am not even sure if this is possible so I posted the question to get some support